# Pester "Should -Invoke does not take pipeline input or ActualValue"

Tags: powershell, pester

I am using the following test code:

```
Describe "Install-Programs"{
    Context "Install-Programs"{
        BeforeAll{
            Mock Start-Process {}
        }
        It "Tests"{
            My-CustomFunction #Should invoke Start-Process
            Should -Invoke Start-Process -Times 1 -Exactly
        }
    }
}
```

And it gives me the following error:
[image: RuntimeException: Should -Invoke does not take pipeline input or ActualValue]

The call to `Start-Process` in `My-CustomFunction` does not get any pipeline input and does not get piped into any pipeline:

```
function My-CustomFunction(){
    ...
    (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($URL, "$($Env:TEMP)\$Index.exe")
    Start-Process -FilePath "$($Env:TEMP)\$Index.exe" -ArgumentList "/S"
    ...
}
```

Comment: We need to see My-CustomFunction ideally to see how you’re using start-process in it. Could you please edit it into your question?

Comment: @MarkWragg u did add the necessary parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get the error you're seeing with the example you've given. I can see that the error is actually indicating that `Should -Invoke` is not being used correctly, and it seems that it thinks it is being provided pipeline input or a value to the `ActualValue` parameter of `Should`. However using the example you gave (with a small edit so that the `downloadfile` line didn't error due to a missing input) works fine for me:

```
Describe "Install-Programs" {
    
    BeforeAll {
        function My-CustomFunction() {
            $URL = 'https://www.google.com'
           (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($URL, "$($Env:TEMP)\$Index.exe")
            Start-Process -FilePath "$($Env:TEMP)\$Index.exe" -ArgumentList "/S"
        }
    }

    Context "Install-Programs" {
        BeforeAll {
            Mock Start-Process {}
        }
        It "Tests" {
            My-CustomFunction
            Should -Invoke Start-Process -Times 1 -Exactly
        }
    }
}
```

I suggest double checking how/where you're using `Should -Invoke` to ensure its not receiving some input that you didn't intend.

It might be worth having `My-CustomFunction` returning any value it outputs to a variable. I.e change your test to to this:

```
It "Tests"{
    $MyResult = My-CustomFunction #Should invoke Start-Process
    Should -Invoke Start-Process -Times 1 -Exactly
}
```

It may be your function is returning a value to standard out that is then getting picked up by the `Should`.

Alternatively it could be a bug in the Pester version you are using. I'm using 5.3.1. Check your Pester version via `Get-Module Pester -ListAvailable`.

Comment: You're right, the code which does not call `Start-Process` does somehow interfere